# How to clear localStorage only happen when browser is closed.

Tags: javascript, browser, local-storage

Yes, I want to clear localstorage when browser is closed. 
Onunload and beforeunload not working, because I don't want trigger it when browser refresh. Just only close browser, I want to clear localstorage.
Do you know any solution ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just clear the localStorage when the first page of your application/website loads. How do you expect the browser to execute code after you close it?

Comment: why can't you use sessionstorage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: @AswinRamesh Oh, Yes! It's working. SessionStorage is what I want. Thanks!

Comment: @DongWang how using sessionStorage you share the users logged in session in other tabs